# Javascript not being rendered by Pug

Tags: javascript, pug

I'm trying to use a bit of javascript in Pug to define the current year for the copyright. Should be simple, but nothing I try seems to work.

According to the Pug docs, this should get the job done.

```
    - var copyDate = new Date().getFullYear()
    #copyright &copy; copyDate
```

However, when Pug renders the HTML it returns the variable name (copyDate) rather than the result (2020).

Output:

```
 <div id="copyright">&copy; copyDate</div>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

This is my version of Pug:

```
pug version: 2.0.4
pug-cli version: 1.0.0-alpha6
```

Comment: Welcome Mack to Stackoverflow! Providing your code will make it easier for others to solve your issue. Usually these problems are the result of typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pug compiler doesn't know it's a variable in a string unless you use interpolation like so

```
#copyright &copy; #{copyDate}
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the help!